# API to create/active Binance grid strategy

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

Does Binance Exchange provide the API to create/active/end a grid strategy trading?

If has, please give some reference links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that there is no way to create a Binance grid strategy (SPOT/FUTURE) by API.

A lot of people were asking for this on the [Binance API Community](https://t.me/binance_api_english). And the answer is NO for the time being

Comment: I have been wondering what could be the reason why the exchanges don't want to invest in this topic, which happens to be in high demand. Do you have any hypotheses?